# Range form field type

Tags: xml, module-params, fields

I read [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types) that there's a new range form field type since J! 3.2 that will provide a horizontal scroll bar to specify a value in a range.

But when I opened the [description page](https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/Range_form_field_type), there is no instruction how to use it.

Anybody knows how to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When ever in doubt about Joomla's form fields, have a look at the following directory, where you will find each one.

> libraries/joomla/form/fields

To get a range form field, you can use the following:

```
<field 
    name="range" 
    type="range" 
    default="1" 
    label="Choose a number" 
    description="" 
    min="1" 
    max="10" 
    step="1" />
```

The above will give you a slider ranging from `1` to `10`.

Unfortunately this doesn't show you the number you have chosen on the slider, so you will be to use the `onchange=""` attribute or maybe override the form field.

Comment: Ah too bad, I was using bootstrap slider before, and it looks like I have to stick with it for a while until "show the chosen number" fixed. Anyway thanks for the help.